# Node mul_1 required broadcastable shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As a reference / follow up to my question here:[previously asked but no asnwers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501435/concatenate-cnn-model-with-ffn-model#74501435)

I could compile my model by refraining from creating model objects, adding additional dimension and specifying axis to concatenate on

```
def make_model(input_shape, input_shape_feat):
    base_input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
    base_input_layer = normalizer(base_input_layer)

    conv0 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=16, padding="same")(base_input_layer)
    conv0 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv0)
    conv0 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv0)
    conv0 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv0)

    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=8, padding="same")(conv0)
    conv1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv1)

    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, padding="same")(conv1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv2)

    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=8, padding="same")(conv2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv3)

    conv4 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, padding="same")(conv3)
    conv4 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    conv4 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv4)
    conv4 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)

    gap = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(conv4)
    gap = keras.layers.Flatten()(gap)
    gap = keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(1, 32))(gap)


    additional_input_layer = keras.Input(input_shape_feat)
    additional_input_layer = normalizer_feat(additional_input_layer)

    Y = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(additional_input_layer)
    Y = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Y)

    Y = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(Y)
    Y = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Y)

    Y = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(Y)
    Y = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Y)


    Z = keras.layers.concatenate([gap, Y], axis=1)


    Z = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(Z)
    Z = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Z)

    Z = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(Z)
    Z = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Z)

    Z = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(Z)
    Z = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Z)

    Z = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(Z)

    return keras.Model([base_input_layer, additional_input_layer], Z)


model = make_model(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], input_shape_feat=x_train_feat.shape[1:])
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

it actually compiles and shows me the following graph:

[image]

Now I would actually like to fit my model

```
epochs = 100
batch_size = 8

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        "best_model.h5", save_best_only=True, monitor="val_loss"
    ),
    keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=20, min_lr=0.0001
    ),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=50, verbose=1),
]
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=[_get_f1], #    "sparse_categorical_accuracy"
)
history = model.fit(
    [x_train, x_train_feat],
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_split=0.2,
    verbose=1,
)
```

but I get the following error

> ---> 18 history = model.fit(...) Node: 'mul_1' required broadcastable shapes ...

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

The problem arises from the mismatch in dimensions of input (2D) and output (1D) as I have just a class label as output.

The solution is to flatten before final output layer

```
Z = keras.layers.Flatten()(Z)
Z = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(Z)
```