# Error -> Node: 'model_3/batch_normalization_4/AssignMovingAvg/sub' required broadcastable shapes [[{{node model_3/batch_normalization_4/

Tags: deep-learning, model, conv-neural-network

I have a similar error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502240/node-mul-1-required-broadcastable-shapes)
However, I still get the same error even after adding a flattened layer to my model before the output layer, I still get the same error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEAIg.png)
My model summary is [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPojd.png). Kindly, let me know if you would like to see my code.